# Best Practice for SQL Tables names when using sub namespaces

Tags: sql, namespaces, naming-conventions, sql-server-2014

I hope my question is at the correct place to ask.

How do you name your tables if you have something like sub namespaces? (similar to Code Namespaces `Base.Sub.SubSub2`)

We have a Schema of course, but what if I need something more deep?

Microsoft Tables are often seperated with a doller sign `Microsoft$AwesomeNamespace$MoreNamespace$Tablename`

I always feel a bit sick if I see this, especially when I have to create a XSL Schema from the database where the doller sign turns into  `_x0024_`. Underscore looks mad as well (in my opinion). Maybe just use more dots?

> Schema.Application.Base.Sub.TableName
>
> Schema.Application$Base$Sub$TableName
>
> Schema.Application_Base_Sub_TableName

Any suggestions, preferences or ideas?

Kind Regards

EDIT:

Used RDBMS is MSSQL (2014).

Comment: This answer might vary depending upon the specific RDBMS. If possible can you tag for the platform you're using? (I think it might be Microsoft [tag:sql-server]).

Comment: Correct, we have MSSQL (2014)

Answer (score 1):

Using dots would mean that you always need to enclose the table names in square brackets or quotes (`[My.Table]`, `"My.Table"`). That could be annoying pretty quick. And it could be really confusing for database users since the `.` syntax is so strongly associated with `Server.Database.Schema.Object`.

Using a `$` or an `_` has the disadvantage that they are awkward to type, but generally my preference is for the underscore `_` because it visually separates the portions of the name.

Could you put more of the namespace into the schema? `Schema_Application.Table`